# Does Linux have well-known groups and users, other than root?

Tags: users, group

Windows have lots of well-known groups and users that all installations have by default. For example, the `Administrator` user is a member of the `Administrators` group, or any user is a member of the `Users` group, etc. Does Linux have such common groups/users other than `root`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the answer as community wiki because there are many groups.

Note: distributions will have also own rules, and in theory every service (from package) should have own group. We just disregard these (too many), but for few exceptions where it is more standardized (e.g. some distribution use `www-data` instead of the daemon name: reason).

- **root** is the basic group for *root*
- **nogroup** is the group no files should have, so to to make not useful group permissions. (set your daemon to this group if you do not need group permissions).
- **wheel** is the group of root administrator, `sudo` may use it, or just the name
- **daemon** is the default group for daemons, but each deamon should use own group to keep things segregated (and so if one daemon got compromised, the other should be ok).
- **tty** is for consoles
- **man** is for man pages, or better: for `man` to write the cached man pages
- **users** should contains all normal users
- **staff** should contain staff users (what they can do depends on the distribution)
- **adm** should be for admins. Log files often use this groups
- **mail** for mailboxes. `mail` group write, specific user can read (set to each mailbox).
- **disk** for disk devices. E.g. you can give a program disk permission to check from time to time disks (e.g. fdisk), without giving it too much permissions (OTOH if one can write to disk, can overwrite all files).

etc.